# Looking for google-api-services BOM or compatibility matrix

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

I am working on a project that involves different libraries out of the google-api-services*
My pom includes

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
        <version></version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version></version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
        <version></version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
        <version></version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-admin-directory</artifactId>
        <version></version>
    </dependency>
```

I am having some issue with versions mixing where in some cases I get no such method error and some cases different behaviours with the APIs.

Do google provide any Bill of Materials (BOM) with verified compatibility between versions. I can see that they have it for some of the projects like
https://github.com/googleapis/java-shared-dependencies#google-cloud-shared-dependencies but I can find it to the above.

Comment: I don't think that exists, but I guess you could ask for it in the corresponding repositories (for example at https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/issues).

Comment: I opened https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/issues/675, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I got a response from google team to github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/issues/675
Common dependencies BOMs, those would be a better place to start:
https://github.com/googleapis/java-shared-dependencies
https://github.com/googleapis/java-cloud-bom